# Mutate DNA sequence with ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a simple class that models random mutations in a DNA string. It introduces a random (A C G T) character into a random location. I would like to introduce a way for specifying a rate of mutation.

Is there a way I can specify how to:

- Mutate the sequence given an error rate. (e.g. 1 in 1000) ?
- A way to bias the mutation (choose G<->A or C<->T more frequently)?

here is my current implementation that takes care of random changes only.

```
class DNA
  attr_accessor :number_of_mutations
  attr_accessor :seq

  NUCLEOTIDES = ['A','C','T','G']

  #random positions
  def random_pos
    (1..seq.length).to_a.sample(number_of_mutations)
  end

  #pick a random nucleotide
  def random_nucleotide
    NUCLEOTIDES.sample
  end

  #generate a random seq
  def random_seq
    (1..number_of_mutations).map{NUCLEOTIDES[rand(NUCLEOTIDES.length)]}
  end

  def mutate
    #pick a random position
    positions = random_pos

    #pick a random nucleotide
    nucleotides = random_seq

    #insert the random nucleotide at the random position in the seq
    positions.zip(nucleotides).map do |pos,nuc|
      seq[pos] = nuc.downcase
    end
    seq
  end
end

d = DNA.new
d.number_of_mutations = 1
d.seq = "AAAAAA"
puts d.mutate  #will introduce a single random DNA base at a random location
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa edited to highlight the question.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I believe the reason is that readers do not understand your question.  I am among them.  You need to clarify the meaning of both "Mutate the sequence given an error rate. (e.g. 1 in 1000)?" and "A way to bias the mutation (choose G<->A or C<->T more frequently)?".

Answer (score 0):

First, you should implement a function which will return a positive result with specified rate. It may be like that:

```
# ==Function will return true with rate probability
def positive?(rate = 0.001) 
  rand((1/rate).round) == 0
end
```

or more complex.

Than you can implement a mechanizm of mutations with specified rate. It can be instances of class Mutators

```
class Mutator
  attr_reader :mutate_way, :probability

  def initialize(options = {})
    @mutate_way = options[:mutate_way]
    @probability = options[:probability]
  end

  def try_mutate        
    do_mutation if positive? @probability
  end  

  def do_mutation
    # your implementation based on @mutate_way
    # link it with DNA
  end
end
```

Than you can define many mutations, like

```
mutations = [
  Mutator.new(:mutate_way => ['A', 'G'], :probability => 100),
  Mutator.new(:mutate_way => ['C', 'T'], :probability => 100),
  Mutator.new(:mutate_way => ['A', 'T'], :probability => 1000),
  Mutator.new(:mutate_way => ['C', 'G'], :probability => 1000)
]
```

And start mutations

```
d.number_of_mutations.times do
  mutations.each.map(&:try_mutate)
end
```

PS. code samples can have some errors, it is just examples.

Comment: thanks a lot @sema! but probability is usually between 0 and 1. Maybe would want to change the probability hash to reflect the fact. Rate should take a value like 1x10-3 or 4x10-7. Do you mind to explain the positive method a little more? Thanks again!

Comment: I edited my answer, now function positive? takes a natural probability rate like 0.001 :) Anyway, I think you need a more complex function to calculate probability.